# Backcasting series with year-on-year growth rate

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, accumulate

I have a dataset containing GDP data and year-on-year growth rates. The growth rate series begins earlier than the GDP data, so I want to use them to recursively backcast the GDP series to extend its sample size.

Each missing value (e.g. 2021:Q4) should equal the value in the same quarter one year ahead (2022:Q4) divided by the year-on-year growth rate in that future period (`i.e. x_t = x_{t+4} / g_{t+4}`). Since each new value depends on a "future" value, I need a way to calculate this recursively.

I have created the desired output using a loop, but would prefer a solution which uses the **purrr::accumulate** function within a **dplyr** workflow.

```
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data set
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 20),
                 gdp = c(rep(NA, 16), cumprod(runif(4, 0.95, 1.05)) * 1000),
                 growth_rate = rnorm(5, mean = 3, sd = 1)) %>% 
  mutate(growth_rate = 1 + growth_rate/100) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) # Sorting the data descending to make the loop work

# for loop which gets a solution
for (i in 5:length(df$growth_rate)){
  df[i, "gdp"] <- df[i-4, "gdp"] / df[i-4, "growth_rate"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are treating the time series for each quarter separately, each with a different initial value from which you would like to extrapolate.

However, `accumulate()` only accepts a single initial value as its `.init` argument. So you will have to split (or group) your data by month, calculate the GDP values based on the corresponding initial value, and finally combine the results.

Below is an example of `accumulate()` for a single quarter to build intuition:

```r
# single quarter
df1 <- df |> filter(lubridate::month(date) == 10)

accumulate(df1$growth_rate,
           `/`,
           .init = df1$gdp[1])
#> [1] 1036.0279 1001.3713  957.7120  929.1814  900.9869  860.4177
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The entire workflow with a grouped dataframe could then look like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 20),
                 gdp = c(rep(NA, 16), cumprod(runif(4, 0.95, 1.05)) * 1000),
                 growth_rate = rnorm(5, mean = 3, sd = 1)) %>% 
  mutate(growth_rate = 1 + growth_rate/100) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) # Sorting the data descending to make the loop work

df |>
  group_by(month = month(date)) |>
  mutate(new = accumulate(
    head(growth_rate, -1), `/`, .init = nth(gdp, 1)
  ))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Groups:   month [4]
#>    date         gdp growth_rate month   new
#>    <date>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2022-10-01 1036.        1.03    10 1036.
#>  2 2022-07-01  998.        1.05     7  998.
#>  3 2022-04-01 1007.        1.03     4 1007.
#>  4 2022-01-01  979.        1.03     1  979.
#>  5 2021-10-01   NA         1.05    10 1001.
#>  6 2021-07-01   NA         1.03     7  953.
#>  7 2021-04-01   NA         1.05     4  976.
#>  8 2021-01-01   NA         1.03     1  950.
#>  9 2020-10-01   NA         1.03    10  958.
#> 10 2020-07-01   NA         1.05     7  921.
#> 11 2020-04-01   NA         1.03     4  932.
#> 12 2020-01-01   NA         1.05     1  921.
#> 13 2019-10-01   NA         1.03    10  929.
#> 14 2019-07-01   NA         1.03     7  881.
#> 15 2019-04-01   NA         1.05     4  901.
#> 16 2019-01-01   NA         1.03     1  879.
#> 17 2018-10-01   NA         1.05    10  901.
#> 18 2018-07-01   NA         1.03     7  855.
#> 19 2018-04-01   NA         1.03     4  862.
#> 20 2018-01-01   NA         1.05     1  850.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Of course, `accumulate()` is not needed here because there already is a function to compute the cumulative product (`cumprod()`) in base R:

```r
df |>
  group_by(month = month(date)) |>
  mutate(new = cumprod(c(nth(gdp, 1), head(growth_rate, -1)^(-1))))
```

Comment: Great solution, really like the clever use of cumprod rather than accumulate.

Comment: The cumprod solution worked very neatly, thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way for this to work if the data is arranged in ascending order? My attempts to modify the solution when `arrange(desc(date))` is dropped haven't worked.